# PHP Form works in common php, but not in Laravel.

Tags: php, laravel, curl

What i'm doing wrong?

**testform.php**

```
<html>
<form action="consulta.php" method="POST">
<label>CNS</label>
<input type="text" name="cns">
<label>CPF</label>
<input type="text" name="cpf">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

**consulta.php**

```
<?php
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 ); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
$cpf = $_POST["cpf"];
$cns = $_POST["cns"];


if ($cns != null){
    $lol = 1;

}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://cadastro.saude.gov.br/cadsusweb/login/actionArmazenarXS.form');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'local/crt.crt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "cnes=NAOPOSSOMOSTRAR&usuario=NAOPOSSOMOSTRAR&senha=NAOPOSSOMOSTRAR");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie-name');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/var/www/ip4.x/file/tmp');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}

//another request preserving the session

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://cadastro.saude.gov.br/cadsusweb/j_security_check');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'local/crt.crt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "j_username=NAOPOSSOMOSTRAR&cnes=NAOPOSSOMOSTRAR&usuario=NAOPOSSOMOSTRAR&j_password=NAOPOSSOMOSTRAR");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie-name');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/var/www/ip4.x/file/tmp');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts

$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://cadastro.saude.gov.br/cadsusweb/restrito/consultar/pesquisar.form?callback=');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'local/crt.crt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "usuario=%7B%22idCorporativo%22%3Anull%2C%22idLocal%22%3Anull%2C%22desabilitarDataQuality%22%3Anull%2C%22obsDesabilitarDataQuality%22%3Anull%2C%22numeroProtocoloPrecadastro%22%3Anull%2C%22protocoloPrimeiroAcesso%22%3Anull%2C%22protocolo%22%3Anull%2C%22solicitarAcessoPortal%22%3Afalse%2C%22encontradoReceita%22%3Anull%2C%22cpf%22%3Anull%2C%22numeroCns%22%3A%22%22%2C%22nome%22%3A%22%22%2C%22nomeSocial%22%3A%22%22%2C%22nomeMae%22%3A%22%22%2C%22nomePai%22%3A%22%22%2C%22sexo%22%3Anull%2C%22sexoDescricao%22%3Anull%2C%22racaCor%22%3Anull%2C%22racaCorDescricao%22%3Anull%2C%22dataObito%22%3Anull%2C%22dataOperacaoObito%22%3Anull%2C%22motivoDeclaracaoObito%22%3Anull%2C%22cnesOperador%22%3Anull%2C%22tipoSanguineo%22%3Anull%2C%22etniaIndigena%22%3Anull%2C%22etniaIndigenaDescricao%22%3Anull%2C%22dataNascimento%22%3A%22%22%2C%22nacionalidade%22%3Anull%2C%22paisNascimentoCodigo%22%3Anull%2C%22paisNascimento%22%3Anull%2C%22municipioNascimentoCodigo%22%3A%22%22%2C%22municipioNascimento%22%3A%22%22%2C%22dataNaturalizacao%22%3Anull%2C%22portariaNaturalizacao%22%3Anull%2C%22dataEntradaBrasil%22%3Anull%2C%22emailPrincipal%22%3Anull%2C%22emailAlternativo%22%3Anull%2C%22emailPrincipalValidado%22%3Anull%2C%22emailAlternativoValidado%22%3Anull%2C%22telefone%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22nomade%22%3Afalse%2C%22enderecoCodigo%22%3Anull%2C%22paisResidenciaCodigo%22%3Anull%2C%22paisResidenciaDescricao%22%3Anull%2C%22enderecoMunicipio%22%3Anull%2C%22enderecoMunicipioCodigo%22%3Anull%2C%22enderecoTipoLogradouro%22%3Anull%2C%22enderecoTipoLogradouroCodigo%22%3Anull%2C%22enderecoLogradouro%22%3Anull%2C%22enderecoNumero%22%3Anull%2C%22enderecoComplemento%22%3Anull%2C%22enderecoBairroCodigo%22%3Anull%2C%22enderecoBairro%22%3Anull%2C%22enderecoCep%22%3Anull%2C%22emailPrincipalCodigo%22%3Anull%2C%22emailAlternativoCodigo%22%3Anull%2C%22dnv%22%3Anull%2C%22numeroInscricaoSocialCodigo%22%3Anull%2C%22numeroInscricaoSocial%22%3Anull%2C%22rgCodigo%22%3Anull%2C%22rgNumero%22%3Anull%2C%22rgOrgaoEmissor%22%3Anull%2C%22rgOrgaoEmissorDescricao%22%3Anull%2C%22rgUf%22%3Anull%2C%22rgDataEmissao%22%3Anull%2C%22tituloEleitorCodigo%22%3Anull%2C%22tituloEleitorNumero%22%3Anull%2C%22tituloEleitorZona%22%3Anull%2C%22tituloEleitorSecao%22%3Anull%2C%22certidao%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ctpsCodigo%22%3Anull%2C%22ctpsNumero%22%3Anull%2C%22ctpsSerie%22%3Anull%2C%22ctpsDataEmissao%22%3Anull%2C%22cnhNumero%22%3Anull%2C%22cnhDataEmissao%22%3Anull%2C%22cnhUf%22%3Anull%2C%22passaporteCodigo%22%3Anull%2C%22passaporteNumero%22%3Anull%2C%22passaportePaisCodigo%22%3Anull%2C%22passaportePais%22%3Anull%2C%22passaporteDataValidade%22%3Anull%2C%22passaporteDataEmissao%22%3Anull%2C%22fotografia%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22situacao%22%3Anull%2C%22dataAlteracao%22%3Anull%2C%22spanSituacao%22%3Anull%2C%22motivoCancelamento%22%3Anull%2C%22spanVip%22%3Anull%2C%22vipDescricao%22%3Anull%2C%22spanProtecao%22%3Anull%2C%22protecaoDescricao%22%3Anull%2C%22motivoNaoHigienizado%22%3Anull%2C%22vivo%22%3Anull%2C%22cartoesAgregados%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22tipoDocumento%22%3A%22CPF%22%2C%22numeroDocumento%22%3A%22$cpf%22%7D&byPassHigienizacao=false&tpPesquisa=identica");
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
$answer = trim($answer,'()');
$answer = json_decode($answer,true);

if ($lol != 1){
$cns = $answer['registro'][0]['numeroCns'];
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://cadastro.saude.gov.br/cadsusweb/restrito/consultar/visualizar.form');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'local/crt.crt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "cns=$cns");
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
$answer = trim($answer,'()');
$answer = json_decode($answer,true);


if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);

}
$nome = $answer['nome'];
$ddd = $answer['telefone'][0]['ddd'];
$telefone = "(".$ddd.") ".$answer['telefone'][0]['numero'];
$nomemae = $answer['nomeMae'];
$cpf = $answer['cpf'];
$nomepai = $answer['nomePai'];
$sexo = $answer['sexo'];
$datanasc = $answer['dataNascimento'];
$cidade = $answer['enderecoMunicipio'];
$rua = $answer['enderecoLogradouro'];
$bairro = $answer['enderecoBairro'];
$numerocasa = $answer['enderecoNumero'];
echo '<h4>Nome:'.$nome;
echo '<h4>CNES:'.$cns;
echo '<h4>CPF:'.$cpf;
echo '<h4>Telefone:'.$telefone;
echo '<h4>Nome da Mãe:'.$nomemae;
echo '<h4>Nome do Pai:'.$nomepai;
echo '<h4>Sexo:'.$sexo;
echo '<h4>Data de Nascimento:'.$datanasc;
echo '<h4>Cidade:'.$cidade;
echo '<h4>Rua:'.$rua;
echo '<h4>Bairro:'.$bairro;
echo '<h4>N Casa:'.$numerocasa;
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo    '</br>';

echo '<div class="st-panel__cont">';
echo '<div class="st-panel__content" id="output">';




?>
```

This way it works. 
But when i do a laravel form, to post to a view with the exactly same code as consulta.php, it just don't works. I think the cURL isn't executing.

***in Laravel:***

**form.blade.php**

```
    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'form', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
    @php
    echo Form::label('cneslabel', 'CNES');
    echo Form::text('cns');
    echo Form::submit('Consultar!');
    @endphp
    @php
    echo "</br>";
    echo Form::label('cneslabel', 'CNES');
    echo Form::text('cpf');
    echo Form::submit('Consultar!', array('class' => 'btn'));
    @endphp
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**web.php (route)**

```
Route::post('/form', function () {
    return view('test');

});
```

**view.blade.php (return of the route)**

> Exactly the same code as in consulta.php, just copied and paste it in the view.

What i am missing?? cURL php don't works with laravel?

Comment: `View` is a place where you output data, not doing logic.

Comment: As @u_mulder states, you're passing the view back without any logic... You need to set your Route to a controller

Comment: How should i do it? Just paste the entire php code in a controller's class?

Comment: `Route::post('/form', 'SomeController@ControllersFunction');`

Comment: My question is: I can copy-paste the php code, inside a controller function? It will work?

Comment: I made it work after 30m. Thanks for don't sugar-coated it.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to resolve it. Some times prodding you in the right direction will ultimately make you learn quicker rather than us fully answering it as you won't learn.

Comment: Make sure to post your answer here so that others who may be stuck with a similar problem in future can use this as a reference

Answer (score 0):

In here you'll have more details about the way **Laravel** handles **Requests**: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests

You have to define a **route** to handle your Reguest in `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::post('form', 'FormController@handle`);
```

A sample method inside `FormController`:

```
public function handle(Request $request)
{
    $cns = $request->cns; // instead of $_POST['cns'];
    $cpf = $request->cpf; // instead of $_POST['cpf'];

    // do whatever you need in here with $cns and $cpf

    // if you want to see all the data on the request, you can try:
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Comment: is Laravel also running `foreach($_POST as &$v){$v=addslashes($v);}`, or is that just WordPress?